# Get O365 Groups from a SharePoint online site using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

In one of my project there is a requirement where the user need all the O365 groups in which the current user is a member of, So that he can check for the files, mails and people in that group. Do I have to use Microsoft Graph API as it will take lots of steps to follow. As I am already using O365 is there any simple way to get the O365 groups using jQuery.

If I have to use Microsoft Graph API, please let me know the steps to follow.

Comment: Have you tried any code from your end?

Comment: Yes I have used GQL which gives all the group of Office 365 but my requirement is to get only those groups in which the current user is  a member of.

Answer (score 0):

This code will list all the groups of the current (logged in) user
Taken from http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/get-the-groups-of-current-user-using-rest-api

```
 <div id='mygroups'></div>
 <script>
 $.ajax({
   url: "/sites/nbntest/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: function(data){
      var mygroups = data.d.Groups.results;
     for (var i =0;i<mygroups.length;i++){
         $('#mygroups')[0].innerHTML += "<br>" + mygroups[i].Title;
     }
},
  error: function(err){}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but this is about O365 group and not SharePoint group. O365 group are generally site where user can share documents, mails and other stuff with in the group.Can you help me in getting O365 group. Really appreciate you feedback Thanks.